# Angular - ngrx store and effects - where to do data transformation?

Tags: angular

I have an angular application with `NGRX store` and `NGRX effects`.

Here is a simplified version of the issue.

Let's say I have a form with `User` data.

When I create the form I used Angular Reactive Forms. The user form group has the following form controllers. This form lives within a UI component called `ui/userform.component.ts`:

- `firstName`
- `lastName`
- `email`

However, when I send this data to the backend, I need to add some metadata such as `id` to the JSON object that is sent.

The form is purely UI and is parented by `feature/add-user.component.ts`, `feature/edit-user.component.ts`, and `duplicate/add-user.component.ts` which uses the `NGRX actions` and `selectors`.

Each of these features has a different set of metadata as well.

With `NGRX store` and `NGRX effects` in mind. Where should I transform this data?

Comment: Greetings! What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can do in the effects..or also can use facade pattern

in the

> Effects

something like:

```
AddSomething$ = createEffect(() =>
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(BusinessActions.AddSomething),
            concatMap((xx) =>
                this._businessService.PostSomething({...xx,Id: Guid().newGuid().toString()}).pipe(
                    map((resp) =>
                        BusinessActions.AddSomethingSuccess({
                            resp
                        })
                    ),
                    catchError((errorMessage) =>
                        of(
                            BusinessActions.AddSomethingError({
                                error: errorMessage,
                            })
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

or in the

> facade

```
 postSomething(xx:MyObj) {
        this.store.dispatch(
            BusinessActions.AddSomething({ xx, id: Guid.new().Tostring() })
        );
    }
```

hope it helps you!!

Answer (score 0):

I´m working on a very similar project right now. For context, in my case I have "users" collection, each user has "groups" that contain "words".

Important note regarding data models:

- **Data models must be truthful**. Don´t try to create universal model for backend, frontend templates and form. So for example, data model of form user should not have id property just because it exists on backend.

So bearing that in mind, I have this set up ( this pattern repeats for each type of item (users, products, etc)):

- Form component dispatches form values. It shouldn´t know who will be consuming dispatched data therefore it shouldn´t be concerned any data transformation
- Utils file/folder containing pure functions for mapping.

```
export const formWordToNewFireWord = (word: FormWord): FireWordCreateRequest => ({
    ...word,
    created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
});

export const formWordToNewWord = (word: FormWord, id: string): Word => ({
    ...word,
    id,
})
```

- Service that is responsible for communicating with backend. If service function requires any data from store, you can select and pipe it inside effect.

```
addWordRequest(word: FireWordCreateRequest, groupId: string, userId: string) {
    return from(this.db.collection(`/users/${userId}/groups/${groupId}/words`).add(word))
}
```

- Effects containing service calls and uses mapper functions, to format incoming and outgoing data.

```
create$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(wordsActions.createFormWord),
    concatLatestFrom((action) => [
        of(formWordToNewFireWord(action.word)),
        of(action.groupId),
        this.store.select(selectUserId),
    ]),
    switchMap(([action, word, groupId, userId]) =>
        this.wordService.addWordRequest(word, groupId, userId).pipe(
            map(res => (formWordToNewWord(action.word, res.id))),
            map((word: Word) => wordsActions.createWordSuccess({ word })),
            catchError(err => of(wordsActions.createWordError(err.message)))
        )
    )
));
```

In this manner we achieve separation of concerns and effects end up being much leaner. Another advantage of using mapper functions, even if you just want to add id, is that instead of writing raw object you get a chance to describe transformation you are performing by naming function, making code cleaner for your coworkers, for example:

```
db.collection().add(formWordToNewFireWord(action.word))
```

instead of

```
db.collection().add({...action.word, created: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()})
```

Keep in mind that architecture depends on size of your project, how clean and how scalable you wish it to be. There would be no technical issue if you decide write all the code inside effect itself.